# Get one result form all results - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is an example table to start out with, so you understand what I'm trying to do:

```
 id  | name   | topic
-----|--------|-------
 1   | jake   | php
 2   | jared  | html
 3   | clay   | css
 4   | jake   | html
 5   | jay    | html
 5   | jay    | php
```

How do I get that there is only php, html, and css isntead of having it say
`php, html, css, html, html, php` instead I want `php, html, css`

Is there some sort of SQL / MySQL command to do this?

Comment: The term for what I think you want here is distinct results.

Comment: DISTINCT works if you do not need id and name with topic. What is the result set you want on this table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT DISTINCT topic FROM your_table;`

`DISTINCT` means to return "distinct" rows; ie: rows that don't match another row already being returned.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY topic